# Setup Getters and Setters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Variables `startStopA...` and `InitialValueA...` from `TableFields.vue` should be moved to store `index.js`. When you move it to store, there is an error "that setters are not set...". I've read a documentation and I tried everything I can think off, but didn't managed to set it right.

`TableFields.vue` component

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="wrapper" v-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>{{ field }}</th>
          <td class="sign">{{ randomSign[index] }}</td>
          <td class="value">{{ initialValues[index].toFixed(2) }}</td>
          <td v-show="$store.state.randomSign[index] === '+'">&#x2B06;</td>
          <td v-show="$store.state.randomSign[index] === '-'">&#x2B07;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <button
        @click="toggleInterval(field)"
        v-if="field === 'A'"
        :class="[startStopA ? 'button-start' : 'button-stop']"
      >
        <span v-show="startStopA">Stop</span>
        <span v-show="!startStopA">Start</span>
      </button>

      <button
        @click="toggleInterval(field)"
        v-if="field === 'B'"
        :class="[startStopB ? 'button-start' : 'button-stop']"
      >
        <span v-show="startStopB">Stop</span>
        <span v-show="!startStopB">Start</span>
      </button>

      <button
        @click="toggleInterval(field)"
        v-if="field === 'C'"
        :class="[startStopC ? 'button-start' : 'button-stop']"
      >
        <span v-show="startStopC">Stop</span>
        <span v-show="!startStopC">Start</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapMutations } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'TableFields',
  data () {
    return {
      startStopA: true,
      startStopB: true,
      startStopC: true,
      initialValueA: 3,
      initialValueB: 3,
      initialValueC: 3,
      arraysInterval: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'changes',
      'timer',
      'fields',
      'signs',
      'randomSign',
      'randomNumbers'
    ]),

    initialValues () {
      let array;
      array = [
        this.initialValueA,
        this.initialValueB,
        this.initialValueC
      ];
      return array;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['replaceNumbersArray']),

    toggleInterval (field) {
      // button toggle
      if (field === 'A') {
        this.startStopA = !this.startStopA;
        if (this.startStopA) {
          this.timer[0] = setInterval(() => {
            this.calculations('A');
          }, 2000);
        } else {
          clearInterval(this.timer[0]);
        }
      }
      if (field === 'B') {
        this.startStopB = !this.startStopB;
        if (this.startStopB) {
          this.timer[1] = setInterval(() => {
            this.calculations('B');
          }, 2000);
        } else {
          clearInterval(this.timer[1]);
        }
      }
      if (field === 'C') {
        this.startStopC = !this.startStopC;
        if (this.startStopC) {
          this.timer[2] = setInterval(() => {
            this.calculations('C');
          }, 2000);
        } else {
          clearInterval(this.timer[2]);
        }
      }
      if (!this.startStopA && !this.startStopB && !this.startStopC) {
        clearInterval(this.arraysInterval);
      }
    },
    calculations (field) {
      this.fields.forEach((value, index) => {
        if (field === value) {
          this.randomSign[index] = this.signs[
            Math.floor(Math.random() * this.signs.length)
          ];
          const date = new Date();
          const newChange = [];

          newChange.field = field;
          newChange.indicator = this.randomSign[index];
          newChange.value = this.randomNumbers[index];
          newChange.time = date.toLocaleTimeString();

          this.changes[index].push(newChange);
        }
      });

      if (field === 'A') {
        this.randomSign[0] === '+'
          ? (this.initialValueA += this.randomNumbers[0])
          : (this.initialValueA -= this.randomNumbers[0]);
      }

      if (field === 'B') {
        this.randomSign[1] === '+'
          ? (this.initialValueB += this.randomNumbers[1])
          : (this.initialValueB -= this.randomNumbers[1]);
      }

      if (field === 'C') {
        this.randomSign[2] === '+'
          ? (this.initialValueC += this.randomNumbers[2])
          : (this.initialValueC -= this.randomNumbers[2]);
      }
    }
  },
  beforeUpdate () {
    const array = [this.startStopA, this.startStopB, this.startStopC];
    array.forEach((value, index) => {
      if (!value) {
        clearInterval(this.timer[index]);
      }
    });
  },
  mounted () {
    console.log(`${this.changes}`);
    this.arraysInterval = setInterval(this.replaceNumbersArray, 2000);

    this.fields.forEach((value, index) => {
      this.timer[index] = setInterval(() => {
        this.calculations(value);
      }, 2000);
    });

    this.initialValueA = this.$root.initialValueA || 3;
    this.initialValueB = this.$root.initialValueB || 3;
    this.initialValueC = this.$root.initialValueC || 3;

    this.startStopA = !this.$root.startStopA || !this.startStopA;
    this.startStopB = !this.$root.startStopB || !this.startStopB;
    this.startStopC = !this.$root.startStopC || !this.startStopC;

  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    clearInterval(this.arraysInterval);

    this.$root.initialValueA = this.initialValueA;
    this.$root.initialValueB = this.initialValueB;
    this.$root.initialValueC = this.initialValueC;

    this.$root.startStopA = !this.startStopA;
    this.$root.startStopB = !this.startStopB;
    this.$root.startStopC = !this.startStopC;

    this.timer.forEach(value => {
      clearInterval(value);
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

`store/index.js` file:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    changes: [],
    timer: [0, 0, 0],
    fields: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    signs: ['+', '-'],
    randomSign: ['+', '+', '+'],
    randomNumbers: []
  },
  mutations: {
    replaceNumbersArray (state) {
      // replace random A, B, C... numbers at time interval
      const A = Number((Math.random() + 1).toFixed(2)); // first number A
      const B = Number((Math.random() + 1).toFixed(2)); // first number B
      const C = Number((Math.random() + 1).toFixed(2)); // first number C
      state.randomNumbers.splice(0, 3, A, B, C);
      console.log(state.randomNumbers);
    }
  }
});

export default store;
```

GitHub repo:
https://github.com/SrdjanMilic/Super-Dynamic-Data

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/super-dynamic-data-djpxe

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a setter for each computed property that you want to mutate, because in Vuejs, computed properties are getter-only by default:

**VueJS docs:**

> Computed properties are by default getter-only, but you can also provide a setter when you need it

A computed property written like that would be like this (again, from the VueJS docs):

```js
fullName: {
    // getter
    get: function () {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
    },
    // setter
    set: function (newValue) {
      var names = newValue.split(' ')
      this.firstName = names[0]
      this.lastName = names[names.length - 1]
    }
  }
```

That said, my advice would be to do this another way if want to make your mutations reusable throughout your codebase, which to implement the mutations as store actions/mutations and trigger them from your component methods (or using mapActions...etc).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I already have stated, I've read a documentation and try to handle it, but the problem is I always get `Computed property "this.Variable" was assigned to but it has no setter.`, no matter how I put it. Please take a try at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/super-dynamic-data-djpxe), to see by yourself.